Is this function correct
import MT5Manager

# Create a ManagerAPI object
manager = MT5Manager.ManagerAPI()

# Connect to the MT5 terminal
manager.Connect("localhost", 443, "admin", "password", MT5Manager.ManagerAPI.EnPumpModes.PUMP_MODE_FULL)

# Create a new user
new_user = manager.CreateUser(
    username="newuser",
    password="newpassword",
    group="users",
    email="newuser@example.com",
    phone="1234567890",
    country="Country",
    city="City",
    address="Address"
)

# Print the login of the newly created user
print(new_user.Login)

# Disconnect from the MT5 terminal
manager.Disconnect()

MT user error
Want to create a new user but unable to create the user.
MT5 manager documention would also be helpful
